# How to get your app to display the correct HTTP error code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using `ASP.NET MVC3` and running the website on `Windows Server 2003`.  I'm trying to figure out how to handle all HTTP errors.  I have implemented code but I sometimes get a 403 error displayed in the browser when a 404 error is returned.

Here is my code that I have implemented:

In my `global.asax.cs`:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MvcApplication app = (MvcApplication)sender;
     HttpContext context = app.Context;
     Exception exception = app.Server.GetLastError();
     context.Response.Clear();
     context.ClearError();
     HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;

     RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
     routeData.Values["controller"] = "Error";
     routeData.Values["action"] = "Index";
     routeData.Values["httpException"] = httpException;

     Server.ClearError();

     IController errorController = new ErrorController();
     errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
}
```

`ErrorController.cs` file:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
     public ActionResult Index()
     {
          ErrorModel model = new ErrorModel();

          HttpException httpException = RouteData.Values["httpException"] as HttpException;
          int httpCode = (httpException == null) ? 500 : httpException.GetHttpCode();

          switch (httpCode)
          {
               case 403:
                    //Response.StatusCode = 403;
                    model.Heading = "Forbidden";
                    model.Message = "You aren't authorised to access this page.";
                    break;
               case 404:
                    //Response.StatusCode = 404;
                    model.Heading = "Page not found";
                    model.Message = "We couldn't find the page you requested.";
                    break;
               case 500:
               default:
                    Response.StatusCode = 500;
                    model.Heading = "Error";
                    model.Message = "Sorry, something went wrong.  It's been logged.";
                    break;
          }

          Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

          return View(model);
     }
}
```

I have nothing set in my web.config.

I want it to display the correct error when the user is trying to access my directories such as `app_code` and similar directories.  Is this possible?

When I type in `http://localhost:43596/app_code` then I see that it seems to be a 404 error but it displays the default 403 error page of IE.  How do I get my code to display the correct HTTP error message?

The reason why I want it this way is because I need to log all attempts if a user is trying to sabotage the site in any way.  I want to be able to see who is doing the wrong accessing.

Answer (score 1):

> When I type in `http://localhost:43596/app_code` then I see that it
>   seems to be a 404 error but it displays the default 403 error page of
>   IE.

What's wrong with 403?

> In the HTTP used on the World Wide Web, 403 Forbidden is an HTTP
>   status code returned by a web server when a user requests a web page
>   or media that the server does not allow them to access. In other
>   words, the server can be reached, but the server declined to allow
>   access to the page. **Microsoft IIS responds in
>   the same way when directory listings are denied.**

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403)

When an user is trying to access the `App_Data` folder and if you return 404 it means to the user that the folder not exists in the server but the truth is the folder may or may not exists and since it is a special folder ASP.NET doesn't allow any one to access that and it is forbidden so I think returning 403 is perfectly valid in this case.

[404 vs 403 when directory index is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075300/404-vs-403-when-directory-index-is-missing)

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to review web.config section "customErrors" set "mode=Off"

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
  <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm" mode="RemoteOnly">
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
</customErrors>
```